# What is »Lischuosècho Kiwisi Adoschem.«?

Tags: sources-mekorot

In "Der Golem" of Gustav Meyrink, Schemajah Hillel says:

> Einen Augenblick versank er in Nachdenken, und ich hörte ihn einen hebräischen Satz murmeln: »**Lischuosècho Kiwisi Adoschem.**«

In the Ukrainian translation there's an explanation: I hope for your help, God!

But I can't find those words anywhere to check if it really means what is said in Ukrainian translation.

It says in the novel that it's a Hebrew sentence. It might also be Yiddish, as it is a saying of the rabbi said in the Prague Jewish ghetto. Where should I look for this expression?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The original words are from Bereishis (Genesis) [49:18](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0149.htm#18):

> לִֽישׁוּעָתְךָ֖ קִוִּ֥יתִי יְהוָֽה

Which literally means:

> "For your salvation do I wait, O Lord."

The words are Hebrew, not Yiddish. The book in question is obviously transliterating the words using an Ashkenazic method. In English one might transliterate the phrase "Lishu'asecha Kevisi Adonoy". "Adoschem" (Adoshem) would be a euphemism for the Divine Name, which is pronounced "Adonoy".